# iReport: List parameter values (without database connection)

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to make PDF reports for my website with JasperReports and designing the report with iReport.

I don't want to use a database connection, I want to pass all the data directly from Java. For example, I want to pass a list of strings (names of users), and simply list that names in my PDF. I see that iReport offers a List component but I don't know how to use it, because all the documentation I found talks about listing data obtained from a database.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: You can look at [JavaBean Data Sources](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources) sample. You can also find a lot of samples in *JasperReports* distribution package (in *demo* folder). The sample of using *List* component is at *demo\samples\list* folder.

Comment: Alternatively use an XML data source. There are examples with JasperReports, too.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing it is by following:

First of all create a parameter of type java.uti.list say, name,
Create a field to display that parameter
Goto text field expression and replace $F{field_name} by $P{Name}.get(1).toString()
This prints the 2nd item in the list

I haven't found a way to loop through the list to print out every item.

Comment: Well, the op could create one such field per possible list entry and make displaying it optional. Very verbose script. But doable.